# How to replace text in a specific line between first appearence of a symbol and second appearence of it

Tags: bash, shell

So, let's say I have some text file like this:

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:ffff:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll
```

and I need a command that makes me able to replace what is in between the first and second `:` in a variable line.
I managed to do something like this but it's obviously just adding the text in the middle: sed $lineNumber' s/:/:'$pass'/' users.txt

the result given by the command should be someting like this if I want to replace what is in between the first and second ":" of the second line with "asd"

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:asd:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll
```

Comment: Do you always know the exact line number, or is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 2):

A job for `awk`:

```
awk -v col="2" -v row="2" -v sep=":" -v new="asd" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=sep} NR==row{$col=new} {print}' file
```

or

```
awk 'NR==row{$col=new}1' col='2' row='2' FS=':' OFS=':' new='asd' file
```

Output:

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:asd:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression that matches the entire part that you want to replace, e.g.,

```
sed "$lineNumber s/:[^:]\+/:$pass/" users.txt
#                   ^^^^^^ = not : one or more times
```

Comment: You posted about the same time as Abelisto, so I give you the same comment:
I like `sed`, but it is difficult here. Try `pass="&/\2"`.

Comment: Cyrus' answer is better for this because it handles the inevitable funny characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you want shell variables to get expanded, use double quotes in sed command:

```
sed "$var1 s/:/:$var2/" file
```

Comment: How about `var2="&/\2"` ?