# How to replace between symbols with sed command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

So I recently asked for help with a sed command for replacing the text between the first and second appearence of a symbol. This is the link to that question: [How to replace text in a specific line between first appearence of a symbol and second appearence of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341380/how-to-replace-text-in-a-specific-line-between-first-appearence-of-a-symbol-and)

Now I need something similar, replacing between the second and third appearence, and third to the end of the line

Let's say I have this text file:

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:ffff:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll
```

```
sed "${lineNumber}s/:[^:]*/:${passwd}/" users.txt
```

What this line does is replacing between first and second ":" in a given line, so the question is how should the command be for replacing between second and third ":", and third to end of the line.

So, for example, the output for replacing between the second and third in the third line with "####" would look like this:

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:ffff:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:####
```

and the code

```
sed "${lineNumber}s/:[^:]*/:${passwd}/" users.txt
                    ^^^^^^ I think that is what should be replaced
```

Comment: Can you explain why you haven't accepted any of the answers to your previous question?

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output in your question in CODE TAGS to make question more clear.

Comment: the answer given in the previous question was useful and works but now I need a different command for the different output I'm looking for. It's my first year with bash so I'm a beginner and can't modify code very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -E "${lineNumber} s/^(([^:]*:){2})[^:]*/\1${passwd}/"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/BnSGK5):

```sh
s='aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:ffff:gggg:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll'
passwd='newpass'
lineNumber=2
sed -E "${lineNumber} s/^(([^:]*:){2})[^:]*/\1${passwd}/" <<< "$s"
```

Output (see the text between the second and third colon on the second line):

```
aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd
eeee:ffff:newpass:hhhh
iiii:jjjj:kkkk:llll
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(([^:]*:){2})` - Group 1 (this value is referred to with the `\1` placeholder from the regex replacement pattern): two occurrences of any chars other than `:` and then `:`
- `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`.

Note that `{2}` is a range quantifier that matches its modified pattern a specified amount of times. If you change it to `{3}`, it will replace after the third occurrence of a `:` char.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ${lineNumber}'s/[^:]*/'${passwd}'/3' file
```

Substitute the 3rd occurrence of non-colons with the variable `$passwd` on the line numbered `$lineNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ruby which can do what sed/awk/grep can do and what they cannot do, so you do not have to carry different tools with you. In this example, you can use:

```
ruby -pe '$_.sub!(/(:[^:]*:)([^:]*)/, "\\1XXX")'
```

which means to match [a] "a colon, anything not containing a colon, another colon" and [b] "anything not containing a colon", and put back [a] (\\1) and replace [b] with XXX which is supposedly a password.